# Keep simulated Keypress inside application (java)

Tags: java, io, keyevent

I am developing an extension for a java Program to automate a task.
For that I need to simulate Keyevents that stay inside the Application.
If I use the Java.awt.robot Api the keyevent is sent to other windows/applications if they are focused.
Is there a way to simulate the Keyevent only inside the java application?
(unfortunately I cannot overwrite the Keyhandling from the Application I am extending.)

Comment: One way: use JNA to give the application of interest focus before sending keystrokes

Comment: i would like to perform this in the background

Comment: Then you cannot use Robot and will need to delve further into JNA or JNI for an OS-specific solution. If you are very familiar with these utilities as well as your OS and its API, then this shouldn't be a problem, else you've got some work ahead of you.

Comment: If Windows, you probably need to use the post(...) Windows function